# Control camera via Firewire

Tags: sony, firewire, video-camera

Some SONY Cameras have a [FireWire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewire) interface.

Is it possible to control any **camera** functions via FireWire using any [FireWire SDK](http://www.unibrain.com/Products/DriverAPI/FireAPI.html) etc?

- **Tape:** record/stop, forward/rewind
- **Lens:** exposure, zoom, shutter speed, focus, white balance
- **Other:** effects (sepia/invert)

**Found:**

- [Adobe Premiere](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere/) can [control **Tape** playback](http://www.manifest-tech.com/premiere/dvcapture.htm#DV%20Device%20Control) functions (play, forward/rewind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source video editor [kinoDV](http://www.kinodv.org/) does this for all kinds of cameras, including sony. Maybe have a look at the source ?

Comment: Good idea! I'll dig in sometime.